# Outlook persistent saving issue (RoamingSettings.saveAsync)

Tags: outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

For my outlook plugin, it has weird issue when I using **Office.context.roamingSettings.saveAsync**, it looks like any address change inside the callback will cause the saving operation rollback (e.g. window.location.href, window.location.reload, window.location.replace).

Below is the test code:

```
Office.initialize = function (reason) {
        var testStorageVal = Office.context.roamingSettings.get("testStorageVal");
        console.log("onReload", 'val = ' + testStorageVal);

        Office.context.roamingSettings.set("testStorageVal", "value1");
        Office.context.roamingSettings.saveAsync(function (asyncResult) {
            var val = Office.context.roamingSettings.get('testStorageVal');
            console.log("onSaveAsync", 'val = ' + val);
            window.location.reload();
        });
}
```

The results:

- onReload val = undefined OfficeInit.js:10
- onSaveAsync val = value1 OfficeInit.js:15
- onReload val = undefined OfficeInit.js:10

However, similar code for word plugin using **Office.context.document.settings.saveAsync** doesn't have the same issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why Outlook's RoamingSettings object initialized with old values after page re-load/ redirect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44028223/why-outlooks-roamingsettings-object-initialized-with-old-values-after-page-re-l)

Comment: Yeah, I agree, we have the same issue, seems still wait for official patch....:-(