# Outlook Add-in : Not getting Outlook Addin RoamingSettings on OWA after saving the same in Outlook Client

Tags: outlook-web-addins

I am building an outlook-addin which saves the data in the RoamingSettings. 
Using the code :

`Office.context.roamingSettings.set('key1', 'AmIABug');`

Once I save it in RoamingSettings my assumption is that when I open an email on the OutlookWebApp. It will immediately pull that save value when I request for it.

`Office.context.roamingSettings.get('key1');`

However this is not the case.

First, considering that there is an issue with RoamingSettings : Pointed out  here.
[Why Outlook's RoamingSettings object initialized with old values after page re-load/ redirect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44028223/why-outlooks-roamingsettings-object-initialized-with-old-values-after-page-re-l)

Which I was able to overcome with the work around mentioned:
https://github.com/joeparzel/RoamingFix

which seemed to work properly on the Outlook client, however Now. I am using the OutlookWebApp and what I see is that even when I have the OutlookWebApp already open I do not see the new RoamingSettings values when requested even when I close the TaskPane on one email and open the same using another email.

If I refresh the page I get the expected output. Can someone please tell me if RoamingSetting for OWA is only set once when the page loads, unlike the thick client where if I reopen my task pane, it gets the latest values.

In may have I missed something silly, please help.

Comment: Are you setting roaming setting from the thick client and then trying to access roaming settings on Outlook web app/different client?

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT: Yes. That is the case.

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behavior. OWA only loads RoamingSettings once which is why when you reload the page you get the new values. Also note that since you are using a thick client to set the properties and the thick client by default runs in cached mode, there may be cases where you might not get the properties back on owa even after reload for some time since the properties haven't been synced back to exchange from thick client yet. Once thick client's sync kicks in, you should be able to see the props in OWA after a reload.

Comment: Oh ok. Do you have any suggestions on how to have the latest value always available for all clients ? Any other storage mechanism ?

Comment: This is currently not possible using RoamingSettings due to the limitations mentioned above. Could you elaborate on what your use case is to set roaming settings on one client and then immediately have it available on another? That might help us guide you with a work around if any.

Comment: We have our addin login to a third party website (auth2 flow: we plan to store the token here), the login on one client is supposed to carry forward the token to all other clients so I should not need to login on other clients. So use case is I login on Thick client and immediately switch to owa and just continue from there. We have a gmail addon with similar behavior. Would be good to have a pointer as to how this can be done best if above is not recommended.

Comment: Storing token is not recommended in roaming settings, because RoamingSettings can be read or modified by any app that have direct access to the user's mailbox. You can consider storing the token in your addin's backend.  You can use authenticate the user using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/authenticate-a-user-with-an-identity-token